# Extract rows in file where a column value is included in a list?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a huge file of data:

**datatable.txt**

```
id1 england male
id2 germany female
... ... ...
```

I have another list of data:

**indexes.txt**

```
id1
id3
id6
id10
id11
```

I want to extract all rows from **datatable.txt** where the id is included in **indexes.txt**.

Is it possible to do this with awk/sed/grep? The file sizes are so large using R or python is not convenient.

Comment: OP please, test both (awk and join) solutions from below and post their execution times?

Comment: There isn't a single comma in your sample input file so either your real input file is not a CSV or it is but you've chosen to show us something different for some reason. Fix your question so the text and the input are consistent wrt whether or not you have a CSV file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need a simple `awk` as

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next}; $1 in a' indexes.csv datatable.csv
id1 england male
```

1. `FNR==NR{a[$1];next}` will process on `indexes.csv` storing the
   entries of the array as the content of the first column till the end of
   the file.
2. Now on `datatable.csv`, I can match those rows from the first file by doing
       `$1 in a` which will give me all those rows in current file whose
       column `$1`'s value `a[$1]` is same as in other file.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i overlook something, but i build two test files:

```
a1:

id1
id2
id3
id6
id9
id10
```

and

```
a2:

id1 a 1
id2 b 2
id3 c 3
id4 c 4
id5 e 5
id6 f 6
id7 g 7
id8 h 8
id9 i 9
id10 j 10
```

with

`join a1 a2 2> /dev/null`

I get all lines matched by column one.